# Deleting property (verification history) on Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, site-verification

I truly hope someone can shine some light on my stupidity...

**The situation:** With limited knowledge, I added my site (non-www) as a property on GWT. After verifying, I deleted the html file from the server. Three months later, realized my mistake, but only after adding a new owner, verifying again, then deleting the site, then adding the site again (www), then adding/deleting an owner multiple times, verifying multiple times... Thus, to conclude, my verification history is messy messy on both non-www and www, and on both (two different) Google accounts.

**The now:** I've deleted the property(ies) on both Google accounts, thus, there is nothing on both accounts.

**The Question:** Will the property (verification) history be cleared after a "grace period" if you delete the property from your Webmaster Tools account? (No properties are created, no html verification files on server - Google will not try to verify, nor can I use GWT.)

**What I want:** I want to ***create a "clean" property, with no messy verification history!***

Comment: Did you try creating a new account for the www soon after you deleted it? If your account history shows up, it always will else enjoy :)

Comment: @Karan I did yes, account history still there. Thus you are saying, the history will stay forever? Nothing I can do?

Comment: Unfortunately no, may I ask as to why does it bother you?

Comment: @Karan Well, I think because it's there due to my own stupidity, and it should not be relevant to the property. And it's a little bit OCD I think... not correct, not structured, not perfect. :/ But if the reality is what you say, it is what it is - I have to accept it.

Comment: You aren't the only one with a messy history.   Here is a screenshot from one of my sites:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3qUE.png  I had no idea there were so many entries in there until I just looked.   I don't see any way to clear the history, but having a messy verification history shouldn't matter in any way other than your desire for cleanliness.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks so much for your reply! I honestly appreciate it! I don't feel so alone anymore :P And your words is a perfect summary of my problem: "desire for cleanliness."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have clearly mentioned that you saw the history after you deleted and added the property again, nothing can be done and you will have to just live with it.